# How to pass templates location to all views in FastAPI

Tags: jinja2, fastapi

I have a FastAPI web app, where I would like to use a templating language.
Right now, in order to use jinja2 I have to indicate where the templates folder is located by setting a templates variable like this:

```
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")
```

I also have several view files for various pages and purposes, like `home.py`, `about.py`, `db.py` etc.

If I set up a templates variable once in `main.py` and then import it into view files like this:

```
from main import templates
```

I get all kind of circular import errors. So I have to set up a templates variable in every view file separately which is not optimal.

How can I set templates location once in the `main.py` and then make all view files aware of this location?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways you can solve this - move the template configuration to a separate file instead of having it in main (`templating.py` or define it in `__init__.py` in your views directory) so that you can import it from that module instead. A plain import would work in that case.

You can also use the dependency injection feature in FastAPI to inject the templating context in a view function.

Set it up as a `Depends` construct in a separate file (`dependencies.py`, `app_services.py`, `__init__.py` or wherever):

```
def get_templates():
    return Jinja2Templates(directory=...)
```

And then in your views:

```
from dependencies import get_templates

...

@router.get('...')
async def display_xyz(templates: Jinja2Templates = Depends(get_templates))
```